# ICINGA monitor the space of a folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, icinga

I have a icinga server that monitors two Windows servers through NSClient.
I would like to monitor the space of a folder with this path C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs.
Is there any way to monitor this folder with the check_nt?

Thank you very much!